# Conversion format from shell script(.sh) to batch file (.bat)

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, cmd, aix

I'm relatively new regarding AIX and BATCH, I have a question to ask regarding the conversion method. Currently, I have changed the some of the codes from AIX to BATCH however I am currently stuck at how do I convert the code "read" so that the code can run in the cmd.

```
ECHO Delete Queue Manager %QMName% at %LocalServerName% for POP
dltmqm %QMName%
ECHO pause
read dummy
```

Thank you.

Comment: I believe it's `set /P "dummy=Please enter a response: "`.  Salt to taste.  `read dummy` does read one line from stdin and set that to a variable named `dummy`, right?  You can also read a line from a text file with `set /P` and redirection, like `set /P "dummy=" <textfile.txt`

Comment: Instead the last two lines just use command `PAUSE`

Comment: @rojo Yes it is. Alright, I'll try it out in my codes again Thank you!

Comment: @Zsigmond Lőrinczy Oh I see, I'll try that out as well! Thank you

Comment: When you need more windows batches, consider another tool. Use Unix syntax with something like `cgi-bin` or become Windows expert with `Powerscript`.